# Laravel 8 with docker on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, docker, raspberry-pi, arm

I am trying to run current version of laravel on raspberry pi. I have installed 64bit version of ubuntu, howerver, when running sail up to spin the containers, i get this error:

[image]

I have also tried to change the mysql version in the docker-compose.yml
from image: 'mysql:8.0' to
image: 'mysql:5.7@sha256:b3b2703de646600b008cbb2de36b70b21e51e7e93a7fca450d2b08151658b2dd'

however, the MySQL didn't start running within the container.

Can please someone help to make this work?

Comment: mysql is not found from the `library/mysql` registry. You'll have to `docker pull mysql` first to download it from the docker official image hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql). Show your `docker-compose.yml` file content if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pull image first from library before running it , since the image is not found in  library/mysql.

Comment: Thanks for offering your feedback on the user's question.
You may want to supply the why/how the asker is experiencing the issue, what the proposed resolution(s) are and any trade offs or other complexities.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official mysql repo on Github, arm support is available from version 8.0, but the builds of those images are not available on the docker hub. This is also the reason of this error

You have 3 options:

1. grab the Dockerfile from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile and build it on your own on the raspberry pi
2. use the mysql fork `mariadb` https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
3. <strike>try to specify `platform: linux/x86_64` in the mysql service of your docker-compose.yml</strike>

Comment: I have tried option 3, however I get an error saying that the platform attribute is not supported. Will try option 2 and let you know :)

Comment: @MartinSagat did you get the database running with the option 2?